# Sending messages to a Msmq queue accepting a password

Tags: authentication, msmq

Isn't it possible to set a password on a message and congifure the msmq queue to accept messages with that password? I'm having trouble configuring my remote queue to accept messages from an asp.net site (network service account). I want my queue to be authenticated (just a checkbox on the queue), but I'm unable to add the Network Service from a remote machine to the users in the security tab. If I leave the checkbox Authenticate unchecked, then everyone can just send a message to the queue.

If I check the checkbox Authenticated, and I try sending a message to the queue from a Console Application, it does work. My Console Application runs under my account and in the security tab of the queue I added myself (on the remote server). But how to give access to the Network Service of my local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Isn't it possible to set a password on a message and congifure the msmq queue to accept messages with that password?" No.

MSMQ impersonates the user account sending the message. MSMQ finds the certificate in Active Directory for that user account to be used to sign the message. Once delivered, the destination checks AD for the certificate to validate the sender.

The network service account is a local one and so doesn't exist in AD and can't have a certificate to use for authentication.